# hprof file format

Tags: java, hprof

Does anyone know a reference for the .hprof (binary heap dumps) file format?

Does anyone know libraries that handle .hprof files? I know that [hat](https://hat.dev.java.net/) does that and also [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) through a NetBeans plugin. But are there others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [SAP Memory Analyzer](https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Java/Java%20Memory%20Analysis).

Comment: Adamski, thanks for the link.
I browsed the source and in the AbstractParser class I found a reference to https://heap-snapshot.dev.java.net/files/documents/4282/31543/hprof-binary-format.html

So, I guess for the file format reference, that's the answer.

Comment: And now... 'The Answer' has expired... dead link.

Comment: Here's an [updated link](https://java.net/downloads/heap-snapshot/hprof-binary-format.html).

Answer (score 8):

Hi as long as there is no more hprof agent with it doc we can only use code as a format specification.

So here is few links.

first of all here is old doc for hprof agent, it could be redundant but stil
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/raw-file/tip/src/share/demo/jvmti/hprof/manual.html you can find hprof specification section in it.

Next, here is heap dumper and hprof spec from jvm code
link to openjdk repo

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/9a73a4e4011f/src/hotspot/share/services/heapDumper.cpp

link to github mirror

https://github.com/unofficial-openjdk/openjdk/blob/60b7a8f8661234c389e247942a0012da30146a57/src/hotspot/share/services/heapDumper.cpp#L58